# Access to read/write of user google drive data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm wondering is there anyway to access user cloud data ? Yes with login confirmation and OpenID for example. Is this even possible ? If not can you suggest a better way of doing this?

I want to store a bit of data on the user cloud and access it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing user data in their own storage, [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive) is the correct solution. You can ask the user to authorize using OAuth 2.0, and once you have gained an authorization token, you can use it to store files.

For an added benefit using the Google Drive SDK, you can use the [`drive.file`](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes) scope so that the user will grant you only access to files you have created in Drive (and not their whole drive).